# HTTPリクエストで毎リクエストごとにnonceを増加させたい

Tags: ruby, api, http

coincheckのAPIと、gemを使用してアプリをつくっています。
2つのリクエストを、間を置かず続けて実行しようとしたところ、

```
{"success"=>false, "error"=>"Nonce must be incremented"}
```

というエラーが返ってきました。
ドキュメントには

```
ACCESS-NONCE 毎リクエストごとに増加する必要のある正の整数。通常はUNIXタイムスタンプを用います。最大値は 9223372036854775807 です。APIキーごとに管理されます。
```

https://coincheck.com/ja/documents/exchange/api#auth

と書かれていますが、どのようにすればnonceを毎リクエストごとに増やすことができるのでしょうか。
gemはこちらのものを使用しています。
https://github.com/coincheckjp/ruby_coincheck_client

該当部分のコードは以下です。

```
  response = @cc.create_orders(market_buy_amount:10000,order_type: "market_buy")
  p result = JSON.parse(response.body)

  # responseがsuccsess= trueならsend処理に入る
  p result['success']
  if result['success'] == true then
     #送金処理。ここでエラー
     response = @cc.create_send_money(address: "xxxx", amount: "0.1")
  end
```

Comment: 「通常はUNIXタイムスタンプを」とありますが、UNIXタイムスタンプ以外が良いのでしょうか。

Comment: 下記URLのライブラリのget_signatureメソッド(232行)で、RubyのTime.nowメソッドを用いてUNIXタイムスタンプを取得しているのですが、一度目のリクエスト(create_orders)から二度目のリクエスト(creare_send_money)までの間にUNIXタイム=nonceが増えていないようなのです。https://github.com/coincheckjp/ruby_coincheck_client/blob/master/lib/ruby_coincheck_client/coincheck_client.rb

Answer (score 2):

現在、該当のgemは以下のpull-requestにて現象を解決済みのようです。
https://github.com/coincheckjp/ruby_coincheck_client/pull/7

Answer (score 0):

"間を置かず続けて実行"と書かれてますが、1秒経過していないということでしょうか？ だとしたらUNIXタイムスタンプを使うという仕様上、暗黙的に1秒間経たないアクセスを禁止してる気もするのですが…。

技術的な解決としては秒じゃなくてミリ秒やマイクロ秒を使えば問題ないと思います。

```
-Time.now.to_i.to_s
+Time.now.to_i.to_s + format('%06d', Time.now.usec)
```

Comment: ①Time.now.to_i.to_s + format('%06d', Time.now.usec)

ライブラリの該当箇所をこのコードに置き換えプログラムを走らせたところ、1つ目のリクエストが実行されず、「Nonce must be incremented」というエラーコードが帰ってきました。

②1つ目のリクエストから1秒経った後に2つめのリクエストを実行したいのですが、マルチスレッドや遅延実行といった手法を用いればよいのでしょうか？